# Is it possible to remap mouse buttons without any third-party software?

Tags: applescript, command-line, mouse

I have a (Logitech MX Master 3S) mouse that I use with my company provided Mac, but I can't install any third party software to configure its buttons, at all, per security policy. Is there a way I can achieve this with command line commands and/or Apple Script?

The main change I'd love to do is assign 'forward' and 'back' buttons to 'copy' and 'paste', e.g.

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: In short, no. I think this would be time to ask your IT department about installing the correct support software for your mouse.

Comment: For your side buttons, you could use [this](https://github.com/archagon/sensible-side-buttons). Since it's open-source, you can modify the code in your fork if you wish.

Comment: If the mouse is provided by your company, then they should provide support for it. If the mouse enables you to be more productive, and/or provides ergonomic benefits, for carpal tunnel syndrome or other medical reasons, then the support needs to be provided. Personally, I rankle at IT departments which restrict personnel from working to the best of their ability with seemingly meaningless knee-jerk restrictions like this. Where I work, we bend over backwards.